# 2 issues - reading multiple files using vb.net and eliminating single space between pipes after removing multiple spaces

Tags: vb.net, whitespace

I need to read through multiple files stored in one folder. As I'm reading through each file, I need to remove all whitespace before and after the pipes.  I used regex to remove mostof the white space, but am left with one space between pipes when the field is null.  With this code, I can read a hard coded file name (one).  How can I change that to read all files in the directory (folder)?

```
 Dim fileEntries As String() = Directory.GetFiles("C:\Documents and Settings\Desktop\files\")
    For Each fileName As String In fileEntries
        Dim FileReader As StreamReader
        FileReader = New StreamReader(fileName)
        Dim FileWriter As StreamWriter
         '***The following code doesn't work.
        'FileWriter = New StreamWriter("C:\Documents and Settings\Desktop\NewFiles" & fileName & "done.txt")  
        While (FileReader.Peek <> -1)
            Dim str As String = FileReader.ReadLine()
            str = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(str, "\s{2,}", "")
            FileWriter.WriteLine(str)
        End While
        FileWriter.Close()
    Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx) method. It returns string array and you can go through each file name using for/foreach

```
Dim fileEntries As String() = Directory.GetFiles("C:\Documents and Settings\Desktop\files\")
For Each fileName As String In fileEntries
    FileReader = New StreamReader(fileName)
...
Next
```

**EDIT**

it's still easier to use ReadAllLinesand and WriteAllLines

```
Dim files As String() = Directory.GetFiles("C:\Documents and Settings\Desktop\files\")
For Each f As String In files
    Dim lines As String() = File.ReadAllLines(f)

    For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Length - 1
        lines(i) = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(lines(i), "\s{2,}", "")
    Next

    File.WriteAllLines(f, lines)
Next
```

Comment: Thanks!  That works great for reading the files.  How do I write the data to separate files?  With the added code, right now it's appending everything to one file.

Comment: @SelliS instead of FileReader/Writer simply use File.ReadAllText() and File.WriteAllText()

Comment: I tried that before, but then it was writing all lines as one large string.  The data is a pipe delimited file with 10's of thousands of lines of data.  Each line represents a data record.

Comment: code is changed above, but I have commented out the File Writer file path, as what is there doesn't work.

Comment: see my edit. also note, "it doesn't work" is a bad description of the problem. You should tell us an exception or other possible errors. In your case the first problem is that you are saving the contents to one file, replace the hard coded string with `fileName`

Comment: Sorry about that.  Yes, I will include error message next time.  I will try your suggestion at work tomorrow. It looks like it might work.  I couldn't find the "ReadAllLines" method when searching earlier.

Comment: The second issue with this code...the original file looks similar to this:

Comment: The second issue with this code...the original file looks similar to this:  CR2010000784CRAXWS|1000      |D   | | |7/10/2010  | | |1|; The above code gets rid of the spaces where data is found between pipes, but doesn't get rid of the spaces where no data is found.  The above code does this:  CR2010000784CRAXWS|1000|D| | |7/10/2010| |1|.  I still need to get rid of the blank spaces in the null fields.  The results should look like this: CR2010000784CRAXWS|1000|D|||7/10/2010||1|;  I've tried using str.Replace("| |","||"), but that doesn't work. Spaces aren't removed. Any suggestions?

Comment: @SelliS `str.Replace(" |","|")`